# Returning None instead of Option in Scala gives Compilation Error

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

This is a simple question that I cant just figure out:

The following code gives the following compilation error:

```
def parseJson(q: String) = Option[JsValue]{
    try{
            Json.parse(q)
    }catch{
        case e: com.codahale.jerkson.ParsingException => None
    }
}
```

Error

```
[error]  found   : None.type (with underlying type object None)
[error]  required: play.api.libs.json.JsValue
[error]             case e: com.codahale.jerkson.ParsingException => None
```

Why cant I return None considering my response type is Option[JsValue]?

Comment: You may want to consider taking a look at `scala.util.{ Try, Success, Failure }` in Scala 2.10.0.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You actually want to put `Json.parse(q)` into `Some()` and not wrapping the whole code in an `Option[JsValue]`, but using it as signature:

```
def parseJson(q: String): Option[JsValue] = {
    try{
       Some(Json.parse(q))
    }catch{
       case e: com.codahale.jerkson.ParsingException => None
    }
}
```

But anyway, you should prefer using [scala.util.control.Exception](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.control.Exception$):

```
 import scala.util.control.Exception._
 catching(classOf[com.codahale.jerkson.ParsingException]).opt(Json.parse(q))
```

Comment: Im marking you as correct because the Some() was also missing, but thanks to you both.

Comment: Curious why he should be using scala.util.control.Exception. What is this class? Never heard of it.

Comment: Because it could achieve the same behavior in one line instead of four! and in a -imo- nicer style. Check the scaladoc, there is a good introduction about how to use it :) (link in the response)

Answer (score 2):

I think you just got the syntax for the method definition wrong. The way you wrote it you are calling `Option.apply` on the result of the try/catch block. I think you meant to write this:

```
def parseJson(q: String): Option[JsValue] = {
  try {
    Some(Json.parse(q))
  } catch {
    case e: com.codahale.jerkson.ParsingException => None
  }
}
```

Comment: He did no such thing. Please read carefully. The original method definition doesn't define a return type, but rather tries to call the apply method of the Option companion object. The code that Kim posted correctly defines a return type for the method.

Comment: Indeed, my bad, so used to read ': Option.. ="! I check five times trying to spot the diff without success :-(

Comment: @BenKyrlach the fact that the OP wrote *"Why cant I return None considering my response type is Option[JsValue]?"* leads me to think that KimStebel is making the correct assumption

Comment: Kim is correct, I wanted to define the return type and instead put '='!